# Bootstrap multi column form validation visual bug

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am using bootstrap and angularjs to create my forms and validate them. In my registration form I want to use multiple columns if the viewport is large enough.

> `col-md ->`Multiple columns
>   `col-xs ->`Single column form

Actually, if invalid data is given at multiple columns, the help blocks show a weird behavior and create a large white area.

See [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/77WJZx4UkkACaSXkV8vo?p=preview).

How can this visual bug be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is what you need.

I created two containers as follows:

```
<div class="col-md-6"></div>
```

and moved the "Email" and "Last name" to the first container and the two other divs to the second container. Also, I removed the class "col-md-6" from these div:

original code

```
<div ng-class="{'has-error': form.email.$invalid && form.email.$dirty}" class="form-group col-md-6">
```

new code

```
<div ng-class="{'has-error': form.email.$invalid && form.email.$dirty}" class="form-group">
```

That's it! Here's the result:
[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/f4MS4lEkBI0PTpjF0DGe?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, cVplZ. I got a -2 because of that? =/